# How to make Scala dependencies smaller?

Tags: scala, dependencies, package

I'm writing an idea plugin with Scala, it depends on some common scala libraries, and when I package the plugin, its size is near 40M -- very huge.

Is there any way to package only used classes so I can get a smaller package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried Proguard

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-proguard

Some uses of [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) are:

1. Creating more compact code, for smaller code archives, faster
   transfer across networks, faster loading, and smaller memory
   footprints.
2. Making programs and libraries harder to reverse-engineer.
3. Listing dead code, so it can be removed from the source code.
4. Retargeting and preverifying existing class files for Java 6 or higher, to take
   full advantage of their faster class loading.